# MySQL Fixed-Length and Variable-Length Columns?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to generate a little more performance from a particular table full of hundreds of thousands of rows.  There are a few `VARCHAR` fields that I'm converting to `CHAR`.

I'm aware that I won't get the speed benefit of switching to fixed length `CHAR` fields if  any variable length rows exist in my table.  However, when I search for a list of all fixed length–or variable length–field types for MySQL, I come up short.  My table contains a few `DECIMAL` and `DATETIME` fields.  I'm somewhat sure the latter is fixed, but the former?  Not sure.

Does anyone have a definitive list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See from the official MySQL documentation: section [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html) has it all.

Comment: Great.  `VARCHAR, VARBINARY, and the BLOB and TEXT types are variable-length types.`  I'm assuming that's it?  If so, excellent.

Comment: Yep, those are all variable types.

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse, but:  "those are *all* variable types" or "those are *all of the* variable types" ?  I want to make sure I'm not missing any.  ;)

Comment: @Stephen: Those are all of the variable types that I know of. But be warned: if you truly want to be sure you don't miss anything, then you'll also need to learn about how different MySQL storage engines (MyISAM, InnoDB ...) handle these things.

Answer (score 0):

The length of a CHAR column is fixed to the length that you declare when you create the table. The length can be any value from 0 to 255

Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 65,535

I always thought it was better to use VARCHAR..
as the variable length is better than the static CHAR

Comment: Right, `VARCHAR` *is* nice.  But if all of your columns are fixed length, MySQL can burn through your queries faster.